# How to filter URLs that contain white space with preg match?

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match, whitespace

I parse through a text that contains several links. Some of them contain white spaces but have a file ending. My current pattern is:

```
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $links, $match);
```

This works the same way:

```
preg_match_all('/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/', $links, $match);
```

I don't know much about the patterns and didn't find a good tutorial that explains the meaning of all possible patterns and shows examples.

How could I filter an URL like this:
[http://my-url.com/my doc.doc](http://my-url.com/my%20doc.doc) or even [http://my-url.com/my doc with more white spaces.doc](http://my-url.com/my%20doc%20with%20more%20white%20spaces.doc)

The `\s` in that preg_match_all functions stands for a white space. But how could I check if there is a file ending behind one or some white spaces?

Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot filter this kind of url. If I write `Go to http://www.google.com/search and type your search query`. How could you programmatically know that the url is `http://www.google.com/search` or `http://www.google.com/search and type`? Maybe with some natural language analysis but even then it's not obvious.

Comment: [`urlencode`](http://us3.php.net/urlencode) might be what you are looking for

Comment: Ah ok! That's sad, because those URLs exist. I thought I could filter them. But it's ok, I just have to rename the files then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after doing [this really helpful tutorial](http://regexone.com) I finally know how the regex syntax works. After finishing it I experimented a bit on [this site](http://regexpal.com/)

It was pretty easy after figuring out that all hyperlinks in my parsed document were in between quotation marks so I just had to change the regex to:

```
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^()<>"]+#', $links, $match);
```

so that after the `"` it is looking for the next match that begins with `http`.

But that's not the full solution yet. The user Class was right - without rawurlencode the filenames it won't work.

So the next step was this:

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return $needle === "" || substr($haystack, -strlen($needle)) === $needle;
}

if(endsWith($textlink, ".doc") || endsWith($textlink, ".docx") || endsWith($textlink, ".pdf") || endsWith($textlink, ".jpg") || endsWith($textlink, ".jpeg") || endsWith($textlink, ".png")){
        $file = substr( $textlink, strrpos( $textlink, '/' )+1 );
        $rest_url=substr($textlink, 0, strrpos($textlink, '/' )+1 );
        $textlink=$rest_url.rawurlencode($file);            
    }
```

That filters the filenames from the URLs and rawurlencodes them so that the the output links are correct.

Comment: [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com) is also a nice regular expression debugger with visual aids

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make use of PHP's [`FILTER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) functions. ?

```
<?php
$url = "http://my-url.com/my doc.doc";

if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{
    echo "URL is not valid";
}
else
{
    echo "URL is valid";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
URL is not valid
```

Comment: No, that doesn't help at all because I don't know the URLs before. I parse through a text to find them. And even if the URLs or let's say the filenames are stupid they are not invalid and they work in the browser but it seems that it's not possible to filter them :(

Answer (score 2):

this might be what you are looking for which uses [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/urlencode)

```
$file = "my doc with more white spaces.doc";
echo " http://my-url.com/" . urlencode($file);
```

which produces:

`http://my-url.com/my+doc+with+more+white+spaces.doc`

or with [`rawurlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

produces:

`http://my-url.com/my%20doc%20with%20more%20white%20spaces.doc`

**EDIT**: Something like the following might help to parse your urls with [`parse_url`](http://us.php.net/parse_url)

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/E18eY8)

```
$url = 'http://my-url.com/my doc with more white spaces.doc';
$purl = parse_url($url);
$rurl = "";
if(isset($purl['scheme'])){
    $rurl .= $purl['scheme'] . "://";
}
if(isset($purl['host'], $purl['path'])){
    $rurl .= $purl['host'] . rawurlencode($purl['path']);
}
if($rurl === ""){
    $rurl = $url;#error parsing error/invalid url?
}
```

for sub directories you can do

```
$purl['path'] = implode('/', array_map(function($value){return rawurlencode($value);}, explode('/', $purl['path'])));
```

Comment: Thanks! That would work if I would know the URLs before but I get the URLs from parsing through a text so that won't work for me.:(

Comment: Thanks! But actually I didn't even try it because my code already did the job ;) But does your code work with sub directories too? For example: www.my-url.com/subfolder/another_subfolder/my file.doc

Comment: @user2718671 yes it does but it encodes `/` as well so you'd need to explode -> encode -> then implode with `/`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about php but this regex

```
(http|ftp)(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?
```

will match every url even with spaces

I think this regex will do.

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with it because I got following error: "Unknown modifier '('". But preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^()<>"]+#', $links, $match); already does the job because all links are within quotation marks. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
$url = '...';
$url_new = '';
$array = explode(' ',$url);

foreach($array as $name => $val){
    if ($val!=' '){
         $url_new = $url_new.$val;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the URL before. I parse through a text with that preg_match_all function above to get them. I thought it is possible to filter them with another regex that checks if shortly after the whitespace come a fileending (doc|docx|pdf) or something...

Comment: Where do you store you results?

Comment: within an array - every entry is a string with the link

Comment: Ok good. so add foreach for that array after you finish check all of the text with the code i posted inside.

Comment: preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $links, $match); is the filter for parsing through the text so all I get are the incomplete URLs. That's why your function wouldn't help because it's the regex that's the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this regex

```
preg_match_all("/^(?si)(?>\s*)(((?>https?:\/\/(?>www\.)?)?(?=[\.-a-z0-9]{2,253}(?>$|\/|\?|\s))[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,62}(?>\.[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,62})+)(?>(?>\/|\?).*)?)?(?>\s*)$/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/97846)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately it didn't work for me. I'm parsing a whole text and your regex just returns an empty array :(